# Setting up a React application and NodeJS backend in Kubernetes?

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to setup a sample React application wired to a NodeJS backend as two pods in Kubernetes. This is the (mostly) the **default** CRA and NodeJS application with Express i.e. `npx create-react-app my_app`.

Both application runs fine locally through `yarn start` and `npm app.js` respectively. The React application uses a proxy defined in `package.json` to communicate with the NodeJS back-end.

**React package.json**

```
...
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"
...
```

**React Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn
COPY . .
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

**NodeJS Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3001
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

**ui-deployment**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: sample-ui
    namespace: my_namespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my_namespace
      component: sample-ui
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my_namespace
        component: sample-ui
    spec:
      containers:
      - 
        name: sample-ui
        image: xxx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
```

**server-deployment**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: sample-server
    namespace: my_namespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my_namespace
      component: sample-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my_namespace
        component: sample-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - 
        name: sample-server
        image: xxx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3001
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
```

**ui-service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample-ui
  namespace: my_namespace
  labels: {app: sample-ui}
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    component: sample-ui
  ports:
  - name: listen
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
```

**server-service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample-server
  namespace: my_namespace
  labels: {app: sample-server}
spec:
  selector:
    component: sample-server
  ports:
  - name: listen
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3001
```

Both services run fine on my system.

**get svc**

```
sample-server            ClusterIP      10.19.255.171   <none>           3001/TCP                     26m
sample-ui                LoadBalancer   10.19.242.42    34.82.235.125    3000:31074/TCP               26m
```

However, my deployment for the CRA crashes multiple time despite indicating it is still `running`.

**get pods**

```
sample-server-598776c5fc-55jsz                     1/1     Running     0          42m
sample-ui-c75ccb746-qppk2                          1/1     Running     4          2m38s
```

I suspect that my **React Dockerfile** is improperly configured but I'm not sure how to write it to work with a NodeJS backend in kubernetes.

**a) How can I setup my Dockerfile for my CRA such that it will run in a pod?**

**b) How can I setup my docker services and pods such that they communicate?**

Comment: Any information in events ? `kubectl describe deployment sample-ui` ? `kubectl describe pod sample-ui-c75ccb746-qppk2` ? What do you exactly mean by `it crashes` ? If it actually crashes, you should see some information about it in logs. What does `kubectl logs sample-ui-c75ccb746-qppk2` say ?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my Dockerfile in the question. I only get `yarn run v1.17.3
$ react-scripts start` from the kubectl logs.

Comment: Is there anything in pod events ?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use come API gateway in front of your server or you can use ambassador from kubernetes.

Then you can get your client connected to server.

Answer (score 0):

> a) How can I setup my Dockerfile for my CRA such that it will run in a
> pod?

React docker file is looking good you need to check why container of pod is failing.

Using `kubectl describe pod <POD name>` or debug more logs using the command `kubectl logs <pod name>`

> How can I setup my docker services and pods such that they
> communicate?

For this, you are on right track, how server and frontend will communicate in **Kubernetes** using the **service name**.

This might weird at first level but Kubernetes DNS takes care of it.

How if you have two service frontend (sample-ui) and backend (sample-server)

**sample-ui** will send the request to **sample-server** so they get connected that way.

You can also try this by going inside the **sample-ui** POD(container)

```
kubect exec -it sample-ui-c75ccb746-qppk2 -- /bin/bash
```

now you are inside of **sample-ui** container let's send request to **sample-server** from here

if curl not exist you can install it using the `apk install curl` or `apt-get install curl` or `yum install curl`

```
curl http://sample-server:3001
```

Magic you might see response from server.

So your while flow goes like

user coming to **frontend** **load balancer** service > calling **sample-ui** service > **internally** inside kubernetes cluster now your **sample-ui** calling the **sample-server**

All the service that you create inside the K8s will be accesible by it's **name**.